# MySql Join with BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, join

I have a mySql db consisting of such tables:

[image]

How (if it's possible at all) could I use JOINS to get the RESULT out of name/period table? And in simple words how would it work?
I apologize to the noob question. I'm quite new to this.
Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Try to make a clear and complete sentence of **what** you want to get as a result. It helps to build your query.

Comment: if you want to use join you must have relation in between those tables

Comment: My advice is to first rename your tables so that it is clear what information is stored in each of them. for example, time_period is a table that stores start and end dates of a period. what about name/period? what does it represent?

Comment: what you thinking is possible but you need to make little changes in tables.

Comment: Edited with more (starwars-ish) practical diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after hours of attempts I found that the best way to do is would be simply using where:

```
#ALL COOL JOINS HERE    
WHERE Newborn.date BETWEEN time_period.date_start AND time_period.date_end
```

Answer (score 0):

what you thinking is possible but you need to make little changes in tables.The changes are :
1.change the table structure as -

```
a.tab1:
-tab1_id(pk)
-name
-date

b.time_period
-time_period_id(pk)
-tab1_id_fk
-date_start
-date_end.

c.name/period
-time_period_id(fk)
-name
-result
```

create tables listed above and now you can use join in those tables.

Hope it will work.

Comment: the tab1_id_fk in time_period wouldn't make much sense because then I couldn't have more then 1 date get it's time_period